# Pre and post increment in programming

Tags: c, increment

So I was playing around with increments in C and I ran this code

```
int main() {
   int a = 3;
   int b = 8;
   b = a++;
   printf("%d %d",a, b);
return 1;
```

}

Originally I thought, oh yeah that's easy... So I thought it would print out 3 and 3.

This is because a++ is a post increment, and increments the value after it has been used it the function. Instead the answer is

```
a=4
b=3
```

I don't understand how post increment a is adding to a before the function has completed, i.e the printf statement.

Can someone explain why the answer is, what it is.

Thank you

Comment: check the [**syntax tree**, how `++` woks in pre-and-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169145/where-can-i-find-the-implementation-for-the-operator/14169214#14169214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *post* increment is post (after) its use, not after the `printf()`. It's changed before you reach your `printf()` call.

Comment: Right ok thank you that clears things up, so if it were ++a, would they both be 4 then?

Comment: Yes, but don't take my word for it, it's too easy to check to be certain :-)

Comment: Yeah i just wanted to make sure before I checked to see if I had the right train of thought

Answer (score 3):

Imagine postincrement as this function:

```
int postincrement(int* value)
{
    int priorvalue = *value;
    *value = *value + 1;
    return priorvalue; 
}
```

So printf has nothing to do with your increment. Instead, when you write

```
b = a++;
```

Imagine that

```
b = postincremnt(&a);
```

was called, which is perfectly consistent with your results.

Answer (score 1):

The post increment means that first you asign the current value of **a** to **b** and then it increases **a** by 1.
If you had done `b=++a;` then you would get a=4 , b=4

Answer (score 0):

When you did `b = a++;` it works out as `b = a; a = a + 1;`.

If you did `b = ++a;` then it works as `a = a + 1; b = a;`

Hope this makes it clear.