# In which cases i++ and ++i can refer to the same value?

Tags: c, increment

Why is `i++` and `++i` same in the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    int i=5;  

    while(1)  
    {  
        i++;                  /*replacing i++ by ++i also gives 6*/  
        printf("%d",i);  
        break;  
    }  

    return 0; 
}
```

The output is 6. I learnt that the increment operator `i++` has its value the current value of i and causes the stored value of `i` to be incremented.But `i's` value is displayed as 6 though the current value of i is 5. Replacing `i++` by `++i` also gives the same value 6. Why is `i++` and `++i` same in this case and why output is 6 though initial value is 5.

Comment: See also [Pre and post increment in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733015/pre-and-post-increment-in-programming) and [Where can I find the implementation for the ++ operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169145/where-can-i-find-the-implementation-for-the-operator/14169214#14169214)

Answer (score 10):

The order of execution is sequential.

`i++` or for that matter `++i` is a single instruction to be executed at that sequence point, with `i`'s value **not** being used anywhere at that instruction, so it doesn't really matter.

If you do replace `printf("%d",i);` with `printf("%d",i++);` or `printf("%d",++i);` things will be much different.

**EDIT:** I also discovered something that is fairly useful to know. In `C` and `C++`, the prefix unary operator returns an `lvalue`, in contrast to the postfix unary operator, so if you want to, for example, decrement `i` twice, then

```
(i--)--; // is illegal
```

whereas

```
(--i)--; // is perfectly legal and works as intended.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer I found at [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

"++i will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value."

"i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented."

You don't use value which it returns, so it does not matter in your case.

Answer (score 1):

It only changes what value will be set when used in a method.

With `i++` you'll use i in the method, once done i will be increased.

With `++I` first you increase the value and then you use it in the method.

Answer (score 1):

`i++` - add 1 to i returns the old value.

`++i` - add 1 to i, returns the new value.

*In your case :*

`i++` - returns 5 and add 1 to `i` make `i` as 6. If you catch the
return value of `i++` you can get the clear idea. because return will have the value 5.

`++i` - add 1 to `i` and make `i` as 6 then return `i`=6

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()  
{  
    int i=5;  
    while(1)  
    {  
        int post, pre;
        post = i++;  
        printf("post : %d, i: %d\n", post,  i);  
        
        i = 5;
        pre = ++i;
        printf("pre : %d, i: %d\n", pre,  i);  
        break;  
    }  
    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
post : 5, i: 6
pre : 6, i: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 5;
i++;   // implies i = i + 1 ==> 6
       // Even ++i results the same          
printf("%d",i); // Obviously it prints 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign the returned value to a variable or use it as an argument, the result is the exact same.

The primary difference between the two is that ++i increments the variable and only then assigns the value, while i++ assigns first and increments afterwards.